# Create an admin panel for adding table contents

Tags: html-table

I would like to know how to create an admin panel (no need to be a complex one) for adding contents to my html table.

Comment: This is a *HUGE* question. Please go and read up some details on what sort of technology and languages you have at your disposal before then reading up how to use those technologies and languages and *then* asking a [*more specific question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Comment: This is a very wide and general question, I'd come back with at least an attempt at doing something or a specific thing you're not understanding. People at SO are willing to help be won't do everything for you. I'd recommend learning about server side scripting/programming and databases.